# validate method in ActionForm subclass when it is called

Tags: jsp, struts-1

Learning Struts 1.1 using "Jakarta Struts for Dummies" book while reading about `ActionForm` it says

```
validate method: Is called after the `ActionServlet` populates the
form with the request properties and before the form is passed to a particular
`Action` class for processing
```

actually we submit the form with properties(say username or password) and these are populated in request. but here it is saying that `ActionServlet` is populates the form?

I think here form means `ActionForm` or its subclass rite, correct me if I am wrong.

**Here is the form:**

```jsp
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%-- JSTL tag libs --%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="/WEB-INF/fmt.tld" %>
<%-- Struts provided Taglibs --%>
<%@ taglib prefix="html" uri="/WEB-INF/struts-html-el.tld" %>
<html:html locale="true"/>
<head>
    <fmt:setBundle basename="ApplicationResources" />
    <title><fmt:message key="login.title"/></title>
</head>
<body>
<html:errors property="login"/>
<html:form action="login.do" focus="userName">
    <table align="center">
        <tr align="center">
            <td><H1><fmt:message key="login.message"/></H1></td>
        </tr>
        <tr align="center">
            <td>
                <table align="center">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right">
                            <fmt:message key="login.username"/>
                        </td>
                        <td align="left">
                            <html:text  property="userName" 
                                        size="15" 
                                        maxlength="15" />
                            <html:errors property="userName" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>   
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right">
                            <fmt:message key="login.password"/>
                        </td>
                        <td align="left">
                            <html:password  property="password" 
                                            size="15" 
                                            maxlength="15" 
                                            redisplay="false"/>
                            <html:errors property="password" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>   
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" align="center">
                            <html:submit>
                                <fmt:message key="login.button.signon"/>
                            </html:submit>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</html:form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Here is the `LoginForm`:**

```java
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.apache.struts.action.ActionError;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionErrors;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;

/**
 * @author kiran
 *
 */
public class LoginForm extends ActionForm 
{
    private String userName;
    private String password;
    int count=0;

    /**
     * Resets data fields to initial values on loginform
     * @param mapping
     * @param request
     */
    public void reset(ActionMapping mapping, HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        password = "";
        userName = "";
        count++;
        System.out.println("reset method is called"+count+ " time/s");
    }


    /**
     * Performs validation of data on loginform
     * @param mapping
     * @param request
     * @return ActionErrors
     */
    public ActionErrors validate(ActionMapping mapping, HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        System.out.println("validate method is called"+count+" time/s");
        System.out.println(getUserName());
        ActionErrors errors = new ActionErrors();

        if((userName == null) || (userName.length() < 1))
            errors.add("userName", new ActionError("error.username.required"));
        if((password == null) || (password.length() < 1))
            errors.add("password", new ActionError("error.password.required"));

        return errors;

    }
    /**
     * @return String
     */
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    /**
     * @return String
     */
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    /**
     * @param string
     */
    public void setPassword(String string) {
        password = string;
    }

    /**
     * @param string
     */
    public void setUserName(String string) {
        userName = string;
    }

}
```

Comment: Unless you have a *very* good reason to learn Struts 1.1 I'd *strongly* recommend you *don't*. It's thoroughly antiquated. At the *very* least learn Struts 1.2, and avoid it at all if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, *the form* here means *the ActionForm instance*.

Why are you learning a framework (Struts 1) that is officially retired, because obsolete, and not maintained anymore? And why are you learning the 1.1 version of this obsolete framework, whereas its latest version is 1.3.x? Struts 1.1 should not be used anymore since 2004! 9 years ago!

Comment: yes i knew entire struts 1 is under EOL(end of life). i just want to learn struts 2.x . for the foundation i am learning struts 1. i am i in a right phase? or learning directly struts 2 is no difference?

Comment: Struts 2 and Struts 1 are completely different frameworks. Struts 2 is actually Webwork renamed as STruts 2 in hope of attracting more developers. Learn Struts2 directly.

Comment: Thank you. regarding my question asked here. if it is ActionForm instace which is got populated by request properties then can we access the input data through request.getParameter(username); in validate method as it has given request object by its caller? i tried but didn't get right it gave me a null when i put sysout in validate method and ran my application giving some value to username. WHY?

Comment: Without seeing the code and the form or link used to create the request, it's hard to say anything. Edit your question.

Comment: But I don't see any relationship with the code and what you asked here. What is your exact problem?

Comment: can i use input values in the form in validate() through request object. i tried them using     request.getParameter(username); but got null in console. but through getter method i got it. why not with getParameter().

Comment: Because the name of the parameter is "userName". And the userName field probably doesn't contain "userName", but probably "Joe" or "Jack". In short, the code should be `request.getParameter("userName")`, and not `request.getParameter(userName)`. Parameters are also case-sensitive. "username" is not the same as "userName".

Answer (score 0):

The `ActionForm` is populated by the [`RequestProcessor`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.struts/struts-core/1.3.10/org/apache/struts/action/RequestProcessor.java/) in the [`processPopulate()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.struts/struts-core/1.3.10/org/apache/struts/action/RequestProcessor.java#RequestProcessor.processPopulate%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest%2Cjavax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%2Corg.apache.struts.action.ActionForm%2Corg.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping%29) method.

This is a code snippet that shows where the action form is populated:

> ```java
>     // Process any ActionForm bean related to this request
>     ActionForm form = processActionForm(request, response, mapping);
>
>     processPopulate(request, response, form, mapping);
>
>     // Validate any fields of the ActionForm bean, if applicable
>     try {
>         if (!processValidate(request, response, form, mapping)) {
>             return;
>         }
>     } catch (InvalidCancelException e) {
>         ActionForward forward = processException(request, response, e, form, mapping);
>         processForwardConfig(request, response, forward);
>         return;
>     } catch (IOException e) {
>         throw e;
>     } catch (ServletException e) {
>         throw e;
>     }
> ```

Comment: yes thank you, and i have read it in JakartaStrutsforDummies its a good book for struts for starters as name states it for Dummies. it is widly available in internet and page 70 has this info.

Comment: I'd recommend you jakarta struts cookbook, there's plenty ready to use examples, less theory much practice.

Comment: Thank you. regarding my question asked here. if it is ActionForm instace which is got populated by request properties then can we access the input data through request.getParameter(username); in validate method as it has given request object by its caller? i tried but didn't get right it gave me a null when i put sysout in validate method and ran my application giving some value to username. WHY?

Comment: Because the form is usually submitted via the POST method and post data is processed by the request then you could get it as `Map parameters = request.getParameterMap();`. But if you have supplied the URL with parameters in the query string, then you can use `request.getQueryString()` to get all or `request.getParameter()` to get the individual URL parameter value.

Comment: And usually you don't need a `Map` because this map is processed and populated `ActionForm` and in `validate()` you should access the form properties instead of request parameters which may very, depending on the request method and I described in contrast which values you get from `getParameter()` and it could be not what you've actually posted.

Comment: Ok, I think it's difficult to you to distinguish between POST and GET method. If you use GET method you can access them if POST can't. Also, there's not reason to do so, as described earlier.

Comment: means form properties and parameters are different right? properties are based up on the fields of form right.
can't we access values input while submitting the form in valudate() method. i am not using querystring and post method here(in my sample application)

Comment: Access them directly in the form class or via getters, whichever you prefer. But getters and setters should be for each property you submit.

Comment: yes through getter i got the field/property which i entered. But why it is not possible using request.getParameter(username). my method is default(get). and whats the puppose of the request object being sent to validate method? just pretend i am new to struts, actually which i am.

Comment: yeah, first you should get parameter names `getParameterNames()`, then try `getParameterValues(name)`, request could be used the same way you use it in the action, access resources for example. Names are usually prefixed with the form name.